# C++ - Как можно создать приватный массив внутри конструктора класса?

Tags: c++

Я хочу создать класс, в конструкторе которого будет создаваться private wchar_t массив (Или хотя бы будет указываться его размер)

Пример кода:

```
class Class
{
public:
    Class(int width, int height)
    {
        //private: wchar_t screenBuf[width * height]; или вроде того
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::wstring` или `std::vector<wchar_t>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так:

```
#include <memory> // C++ не меньше 14, само собой

class Class
{
    public:
        Class(int width, int height)
        {
            screenBuf = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(width*height);
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> screenBuf;
};
```

Comment: добавьте инклуды заголовочных файлов. А то так не заработает наверное.

Comment: Яволь, мон женераль! А полы помыть не изволите ли приказать?

Comment: В следующий раз, если вопрос будет про полы =).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Class
{
private:
  wchar_t *data;

public:
  Class(int width, int height) : data(new wchar_t [width * height]) {}
  ~Class() { delete [] data; }
}
```

Comment: А деструктор кто будет писать?

Comment: @KoVadim, точно. Написал.

Comment: думаю, там есть ошибка:)

Comment: @KoVadim, да, исправил))